# Select one row from inner join MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a problem, I tried to search around on the web, but can't find a solution to my problem.

I have 2 tables One with tblproducts and one with tblproductImages.

The tblproductImages has a fldProduct_FK that matches the tblproducts fldproductID.

I want to select all the products, but only one image to each product.

Hope someone can help.

```
SELECT * FROM tblProduct AS P
INNER JOIN 
tblProductImage AS I
ON 
P.fldProductID = I.fldProduct_FK
```

Comment: You need some rule to choice an image from a set, f.e. most earlier image, most smaller/bigger image, or something else.

Comment: Someway just to take the first image it gets too?

Comment: Ok, I had wrote the answer, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server this is the perfect example for `cross apply`

```
SELECT *, II.*
    FROM tblProduct AS P 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT top 1 * FROM tblProductImage AS I 
    where P.fldProductID = I.fldProduct_FK
  ) AS II
```

Comment: However remark by Mark Shevchenko is still valid. You have to bother your self with an `ORDER BY` clause in second `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner select:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 fldImageID FROM tblProductImage WHERE fldProduct_FK = tblProduct.fldProductID)
FROM tblProduct
```

Of course, you can't control that image will be selected. It may be the same image always, or not. Also, the query throws an error, if no images can be found.

Comment: Not sure who upvoted this, but it is incorrect syntax and works as an outer join instead of an inner join. Your text is also incorrect, it will throw the error because your syntax is incorrect

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I don't have the required scheme, so I had checked a query on my own tables, it works. Then I translated the query to required scheme, and of course I could make a mistakes.

Comment: @Mark. It is very misleading when "expert's" answer contains errors because sometimes OPs have a combined trouble of typo mistakes and missing logic. In your answer: `TOP` can only be placed preceding field names, and such nested query is allowed only if it returns a SINGLE row with SINGLE column. So it not a solution here in any case

Comment: @KirillSlatin the subselect will only return 1 row and 1 column. According to the question it should return 1 image, so this part is fine

Comment: @KirillSlatin I'd moved `TOP` in my answer.

Comment: Exactly. It will return only one field from another images table, not the whole record. I've tried to play with your approach and I failed to make it work